# How to get y_hat using predict() when both response variable and explanatory variables are log transformed?

Tags: r, logging, transformation, lm, predict

I have a log-log linear function as:

```
lom1 = lm(log(y)~log(x1)+log(x2),data=mod_dt)
```

I want to get y_hat using the same data set and I did

```
yhat = exp(predict(lom1))
```

Result seems off a lot (from comparing with the y-hat I calculated manually in R).

Any reason?

The second related question is, I first added three more columns in the original data set mod_dt for the log transformations of y, x1 and x2. Say, they are named as logy, logx1 and logx2, and then I ran lm:

```
lom2 = lm(logy ~ logx1 + logx2, data=mod_dt)
```

This gives a different set of coefficients.

Can this give a correct y-hat by doing

```
exp(predict(lom2))
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking the exponential should give you correct forecasts, and the two procedures you describe should give the same coefficients and forecasts. But without reproducible code (with data), we cannot tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When a model such as your formula is estimated, it translates to Y ~ X1 * X2 on the untransformed scale. You will need to provide data for examination if you want to get more specific review of your results.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer exactly. Just want to share some of my opinions. A linear regression model assumes E(y) = x * beta. If y is transformed by log, it becomes E(log(y)) = x * beta. However when we try to predict y, usually we don't have exp(E(log(y))) = E(y)

Comment: Agreed, the log-log regression gives you elasticities as coefficients, what is fitting is a function of the form y = x^b which is different from y = bx